# OLED Custom Character not being displayed correctly on Arduino Uno? Too Many?

Tags: arduino, lcd, oled, character-lcd

So I have a bunch of custom characters and they are created like this

```
byte play[8] = { 
  B10000, B11000, B11100, B11110, B11100, B11000, B10000, B00000 };

byte pause[8] = { 
  B11011, B11011, B11011, B11011, B11011, B11011, B11011, B00000 };

byte stopped[8] = { 
  B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B00000 };

byte vol1[8] = { 
  B00000, B00000, B00000, B00000, B00000, B00000, B11111, B00000 };

byte vol2[8] = { 
  B00000, B00000, B00000, B00000, B00000, B11111, B11111, B00000 };

byte vol3[8] = { 
  B00000, B00000, B00000, B00000, B11111, B11111, B11111, B00000 };

byte vol4[8] = { 
  B00000, B00000, B00000, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B00000 };

byte vol5[8] = { 
  B00000, B00000, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B00000 };

byte vol6[8] = { 
  B00000, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B11111, B00000 };
```

And then I create the characters in the `setup()`

```
lcd.begin(16, 2);
lcd.createChar(0, play);
lcd.createChar(1, pause);
lcd.createChar(2, stopped);
lcd.createChar(3, vol1);
lcd.createChar(4, vol2);
lcd.createChar(5, vol3);
lcd.createChar(6, vol4);
lcd.createChar(7, vol5);
lcd.createChar(8, vol6);
```

but when I display the play chracter, I get a square instead of a play logo...

it is displayed with this...

```
lcd.write(byte(0));
```

This worked before I created all the vol characters...is there too many custom characters, or am I missing something?

Comment: What does the documentation / data sheet say about the maximum numer?  If you remove that last few, does it start working again?  Does what you get instead resemble any of the later ones?

Comment: If I removed one custom character it did work...wonder if there is a way to consolidate any of characters

Comment: I was able to swap the play character for a great than symbol, ascii 62, which worked for me

Comment: If indeed limited, then eight custom characters sounds realistic, it being a power of two.